# How do I convert audio to text?

Tags: windows, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

How can we directly convert our speech to text without any effort of typing?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. Is this a desktop app? a server app? some type of web app? will users be speaking to a microphone on a PC? or will there be audio files collected? or will users be using a telephone? are there platform requirements that limit your choices?

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to do this. Windows has a built in speech recognition system that we have used and works quite well. You have to train it for different users. We also use the (commercial) [Dragon](http://shop.nuance.co.uk/store/nuanceeu/en_GB/Content/pbPage.landing)/Nuance tools. These systems can interact with the active areas on the screen (e.g. buttons)

You don't say whether you want this to create documents or whether you wish to issue commands to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

[Convert audio to text : Speech Recognition with XP](http://hubpages.com/hub/audio-to-text-conversion)

Refer this...this will surely help you.. and is the best method for direct and fast conversion of audio to text.. just say and have you audio converted into text! Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with .NET

http://ellismis.com/2012/03/17/converting-or-transcribing-audio-to-text-using-c-and-net-system-speech/